# How do I set if ( ) statement for the url of a link?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

How do I set an if/else condition for the url of a link and not the current page?

I'm having trouble with the 4th line of this code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'studies', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
**if(url=the page I want to link to)** 
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'</a>';
else
echo '<a href="#self" class="anchor-hover">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'</a>';
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the url to a string, then run the if statement for the string

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `==` operator. For example, replace line 4 with:

```
if ( get_permalink() == 'http://example.com' )
```